# Using shadow root to hide data from scrapers

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, web-crawler, web-component

Is the shadow root always accessible from any javascript context in the same window/frame/page as the the root itself?

If it is, then it is not possible to hide data from web scrapers by putting it in a shadow root.

If it is not always accessible (for instance if there is some kind of weird "cross origin" security policy) then the rendered (visible to the user) but not logical DOM content in an element's shadow root could be inaccessible to some javascript contexts on that page -- therefore allowing that data to be hidden from (non extreme OCR) scrapers.

As I am in the data scraper business, I am hoping that it is the former!

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the spec says:

> To facilitate invoking callbacks, each unit of related similar-origin browsing contexts has a processing stack, which is initially empty. Each item in the stack is an element queue, which is initially empty as well. Each item in the element queue is a custom element.

If you want to hide the data, here are two options:

- [iframe context](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#unit-of-related-similar-origin-browsing-contexts)
- [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

**References**

- [Custom Elements Specification](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/)

Comment: I would assume that Google with it's infinite wisdom will just render a page in a headless Chrome and just get the text after rendering? I don't think it's possible to really hide any data from scrapers..